# Which chord is Cm6?

Tags: theory, notation, chord-theory

I am not sure if this is an inversion or some other chord.  Notation is Cm6.  Is this an inversion of C minor chord?  Or is it a sixth chord of some sort - C minor with a sixth added?  Key signature in the song is G major.

Answer (score 7):

Cm6 is C-Eb-G-A. It's Cminor with an added 6th note. Note that the 6th note is from the major scale and melodic minor ascending scale, not the harmonic or natural minor.

Answer (score 4):

Cm6 is C Eb G A.   C minor triad with an added sixth.   It's one of the extended chords that doesn't fit into the "pile of thirds" hierarchy, it's not a Cm13 (C Eb G Bb D [F] A) with missing notes!

And it's just fine in the key of G.  Here's a common, corny even, useage - firmly within a G major tonality.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to the most common use of such symbols, in popular music and jazz transcriptions, Cm6 would be C minor chord with an added 6th (i.e. a natural A).

The figure 6 (written as superscript) can be used to mean a first inversion of a major or minor chord, but that is usually in the context of the so called "roman numeral analisys" of tonal harmony. So in that context a roman numeral in relation to the tonality, not the note name, would normally be used to designate the chord.